# Gerund vs. infinitive: are both forms acceptable for the following examples?

Tags: gerunds, infinitives, gerund-vs-infinitive

1. It is a lesser evil to have *x* than to have *y.*
2. Having *x* is a lesser evil than having *y.*

Which of them are incorrect?

Comment: What makes you think either of them is incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

There's no difference in the meaning of these two sentences and neither is grammatically incorrect. English is flexible that way sometimes. Makes writing poetry a bit easier.